# Catch System.InvalidCastException in external dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, geckofx

I'm currently facing an issue with my .net project & geckoFX.

Sometimes the element "GeckoWebBrower" (i use vb.net & graphical geckofx so this element is generate by the .dll Geckofx-Winforms.dll) give me an error "System.InvalidCastException" wich happen in it's dll "Geckofx-Winforms.dll".

I know how to catch "System.InvalidCastException" error locally (with try/catch) but i don't know how can i catch it in Geckofx-Winforms.dll

I've already reported the issue to geckofx official page but i dont know if they will do something about it and when.

I already have that code :

```
Private Sub InvalidCastHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.InvalidCastException)

    MsgBox("Execption catched")

End Sub
```

But i need to make it catch the errors of the dll with something like that :

```
AddHandler XXX, AddressOf InvalidCastHandler
```

The issue is that i don't know what to put for XXX.

Comment: Are you getting exception when trying to render contol on the form or when you doing some operation? Can you share piece of code where you are getting exception?

Comment: I don't think GeckoFX has an event for when an `InvalidCastException` is thrown. You'd have to use `Try/Catch`. -- Please tell us _when_ you get the exception and also post a complete error message (including StackTrace and InnerException, if any).

Comment: If you download the source code for GeckoFX you should be able to choose to use it as a base for when exceptions is thrown by the control when Visual Studio can't find any related source code.

Comment: *how can i catch it in Geckofx-Winforms.dll* - you can't. Surround code in `try/catch`..